# Possible to instantiate templates using a for loop in a C++14 constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

I've been messing around with an SVN build of clang to experiment with the relaxed rules for `constexpr`. One of the things I've been unable to determine as of yet is whether it's possible to loop through the elements inside a tuple at compile-time in a constexpr function.

Because I don't have a C++14 compliant standard library to test on, I've prepared the following equivalent test:

```
template<int N>
constexpr int foo() {
  return N;
}

constexpr int getSum() {
  auto sum = 0;
  for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    sum += foo<i>();
  }
  return sum;
}

constexpr auto sum = getSum();
```

The interesting part here is `foo<i>()`. In a non-constexpr function I would expect this to fail to compile, because you simply cannot use a runtime int to generate a compile-time instantiation of a template. Because this is a `constexpr` function, however, I question whether this would be possible. In particular, the value is known at compile-time, even if it is allowed to mutate.

I know that the following code *will* compile:

```
constexpr auto nValue = 2;
foo<nValue>();
```

In SVN clang, my first example does not:

```
test2.cpp:19:12: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    sum += foo();
           ^~~~~~
test2.cpp:11:15: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified
      argument for template parameter 'N'
constexpr int foo() {
              ^
```

For starters, I struggle to interpret the second part of this error message. That aside, is it mandated by the C++14 standard, and if so, does anyone know why this syntax wouldn't be allowed (simple oversight or to protect against something)?

Comment: I think that the error is caused by the fact that `i` and `sum` are not `constexpr`.

Comment: Also, please, use `auto` only when there's a real need. In your example you are typing one more character than the equivalent type that is deduced.

Comment: @Jefffrey - Yes, I understand that, but that would make them immutable, which does not seem conceptually necessary. Also, auto is not about typing convenience, it's about correctness, performance, and maintainability. The arguments apply equally well to primitives. Reference: http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: Templates are instantiated at compile time, so template parameters must be constant expressions. It may not be "conceptually necessary," but for now that's how the language is specified. And please, let's not start a holy war over what is essentially a question of style.

Comment: @Casey - That may be the 'standardese' reason, and for that, I thank you, but I would argue that i and sum are 'part of a constant expression' because I could write a constexpr function that used i += sum without issue and they would be a subset of that function. I suppose what I'm looking for is something quotable from the standard (and my next move should be to go read it).

Comment: @Mark, how is `auto` in this case more "performant" than `int`? Also what's incorrect in `int`? Also what maintainability boost does `auto` give in this case?

Comment: @Mark You're looking for § 5.19 in the C++11 standard. It's under [expr.const]

Comment: The `auto` keyword is really all about convenience in writing, there's no difference "performance" wise and "correctness" wise. I can agree that `auto` might be more maintainable in some cases (especially with template functions), but definitely not in this case.

Comment: @Jefffrey - I gave the general reasons. Here it is about maintainability, as it is unlikely I'd introduce a conversion. If I decide to go from int to long long, I can. I recently had to go from double to long double in a project where this proved most useful. In general, it is a good habit, the primitives aren't really all that special, let's not treat them like they are. Let's also end this now - read the gotw, if you agree, great, if not, let's go our separate ways.

Comment: @Rapptz - Many thanks - I'll give that a read, then possibly poke around the standardization forums :).

Comment: @Jefffrey : You are very much missing the point. It's about maintainability, in much the same way as why one would use conceptual typedefs over concrete types.

Comment: @ildjarn "in this case"

Comment: @Jefffrey : If the only drawback to adhering to good practice is typing one extra letter, I cannot see the problem.

Comment: I really wish this would be allowed - even at the const of making the constexpr function _only_ usable at compile time. It would make a bunch of things _so_ much easier...

Comment: Related, [Why isn't a for-loop a compile-time expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37602057/608639) and [Why for-loop isn't a compile time expression and extended constexpr allows for-loop in a constexpr function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42005229/608639).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> That aside, is it mandated by the C++14 standard, and if so, does anyone know why this syntax wouldn't be allowed (simple oversight or to protect against something)?

That's because `constexpr` is not exclusive to compile-time computations or usage. A `constexpr` function is just that, allowing a function (or variable) to be used in a constant expression. Outside of that, they're regular functions. A constant expression just so happens to be required in certain contexts such as `static_assert` or array sizes, etc that are compile-time only situations.

You'll notice in your code that you loop through a variable but the variable you're looping through itself isn't `constexpr` so it isn't a constant expression to be used in that template instantiation of `N`. As it stands, it's no different than doing this in C++11:

```
constexpr bool f(int x) {
    static_assert(x > 10, "..."); // invalid
    return true;
}
```

Which is obviously invalid because as I mentioned earlier, you don't have to use `constexpr` functions in exclusive compile-time situations. For example, nothing is stopping you from doing this:

```
constexpr int times_ten(int x) {
    return x * 10;
}

int main() {
   int a = times_ten(20); // notice, not constexpr
   static_assert(times_ten(20) == 200, "...");
   static_assert(a == 200, "..."); // doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: This argument makes sense, but I've already found cases where constexpr functions will compile only if input parameters are constexpr. This was also because of code in the body, not the function signature; I don't see why this should be any different. The compiler can (theoretically) selectively allow it if it knows that the function is, in fact, being evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: @Mark Unfortunately, as far as the language is concerned template parameters *must* be constant expressions and one way to enable that as far as the language is concerned is `constexpr`, so the variable you're looping through has to be `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late for you, but it might be useful for everybody else finding this SO so therefore here is my answer.

@Rapptz answer is not wrong, but the answer to your question might be 'yes'. Yes, the for loop can't be used as discussed. However you want to iterate over the loop, doesn't have to be with a **for** loop mindset, for example with **recursion** it's possible. It's uglier, but for some users to get something heavy from runtime (which shouldn't be in runtime) to compile-time might be worth it. For some the added ugliness might not be worth sacrificing the code cleanliness, so that's up to everybody to decide, I just want to show that it's possible. The embedded domain where there are tight constraints on resources might worth consideration. With this recursion you can describe many algorithms, you could probably do tail + head like prolog and process one entry at the time, or copy arrays and change once entry in it at the time (poor man's template-centric concatenation without changing the size of the return type). Just there is one limitation, at compile time the 'if' condition for the end of the loop will not be seen. So typical algorithm like this:

```cpp
template<int input>
int factorialTemplateSimpler() {
    if (input < 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return factorialTemplateSimpler<input-1>() * input;
    }
}
```

Wouldn't compile as the toolchain would keep decrementing until it would be terminated (probably after 1000 recursions). For the templates to see the **end-state** you have to explicitly state it like this:

https://godbolt.org/z/d4aKMjqx3

```cpp
template<int N>
constexpr int foo() {
  return N;
}

const int maxLoopIndex = 10;

template<int loopIndex>
constexpr int getSum() {
  return foo<loopIndex>() + getSum<loopIndex + 1>();
}

template<>
constexpr int getSum<maxLoopIndex>() {
  return 0;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto sum = getSum<0>();
    return sum;
}
```

This does what you want, it compiles with C++14, and not sure why it compiles with C++11 too.

Many algorithms have a *special case* to do something special from the typical algorithm and you have to make a separate implementation for it (as the **if** will not be seen when instantiating). And you have to end the loop somewhere as well, so then you have to implement separate the *exit case*. To save you extra typing, it would be best to have the *exit case* and *special case* at the same index, so you do not have to create a duplicate implementation and increase maintenance. Therefore you have to decide if it's better to count in an incrementing or decrementing fashion. So you will then have to only implement the combined special and exit case once. To put it into a context, for something like factorial I would decrement so then the 0-case and end of the loop would be implemented with the same code, and then let the algorithm do the work as it's returning from the deep recursion.

If you do not have any special case and you have to make one special case, for example in the code above, I knew it's safe to return 0 and I knew when you are counting up to 10 but not including it, therefore I made the special case at index 10 and returned 0.

```cpp
template<>
constexpr int getSum<maxLoopIndex>() {
  return 0;
}
```

If that trick is not possible for you, then you have to implement a subset of the algorithm (without the recursion) but stop at index 9 like this:

```
template<>
constexpr int getSum<maxLoopIndex-1>() {
  return foo<maxLoopIndex-1>();
}
```

Note: You can use const variables and equations as long as they are in the compile time.

Full example:

https://godbolt.org/z/eMc93MvW8

```
template<int N>
constexpr int foo() {
  return N;
}

const int maxLoopIndex = 10;

template<int loopIndex>
constexpr int getSum() {
  return foo<loopIndex>() + getSum<loopIndex + 1>();
}

template<>
constexpr int getSum<maxLoopIndex-1>() {
  return foo<maxLoopIndex-1>();
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto sum = getSum<0>();
    return sum;
}
```

Here is an example where it's decrementing to make something easier on you (the end case is at 0):

https://godbolt.org/z/xfzcGMrcq

```
template<int N>
constexpr int foo() {
  return N;
}

template<int index>
constexpr int getSum() {
  return foo<index>() + getSum<index-1>();
}

template<>
constexpr int getSum<0>() {
  return foo<0>();
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto sum = getSum<10 - 1>();  // loop 0..9
    return sum;
}
```

If you would enable C++20 then I got it even to populate at compile time a lookup table with function pointers to your foo instances just to demonstrate that there are a lot of possibilities that can be done at compile time. Full example:

https://godbolt.org/z/c3febn36v

```cpp
template<int N>
constexpr int foo() {
  return N;
}

const int lookupTableSize = 10;

template <int lookupIndex>
constexpr std::array<int(*)(), lookupTableSize> populateLookupTable() {
    auto result = populateLookupTable<lookupIndex - 1>();
    result[lookupIndex] = foo<lookupIndex>;

    return result;
}


template <>
constexpr std::array<int(*)(), lookupTableSize> populateLookupTable<0>() {
    std::array<int(*)(), lookupTableSize> lookupTable;
    lookupTable[0] = foo<0>;
    return lookupTable;
}


const auto lookupTable = populateLookupTable<lookupTableSize - 1>();

int main() {
    return lookupTable[2]();
}
```

Another example here is to populate cos lookup table:

https://godbolt.org/z/ETPvx4nex

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>

const int lookupTableSize = 32;

template <int lookupIndex>
constexpr std::array<int8_t, lookupTableSize> populateLookupTable() {
    auto previousResult = populateLookupTable<lookupIndex + 1>();

    auto pi = acosf(-1);
    auto inRadians = (((float)lookupIndex)/lookupTableSize) * 2 * pi;
    previousResult[lookupIndex] = 127 * std::clamp(cosf(inRadians), -1.0f, 1.0f);

    return previousResult;
}


template <>
constexpr std::array<int8_t, lookupTableSize> populateLookupTable<lookupTableSize>() {
    return { 0 };
}


const auto lookupTable = populateLookupTable<0>();

int main() {
    return lookupTable[2];
}
```