# Why isn't a for-loop a compile-time expression?

Tags: c++, constexpr

If I want to do something like iterate over a tuple, I have to resort to crazy template metaprogramming and template helper specializations. For example, the following program won't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

constexpr auto multiple_return_values()
{
    return std::make_tuple(3, 3.14, "pi");
}

template <typename T>
constexpr void foo(T t)
{
    for (auto i = 0u; i < std::tuple_size<T>::value; ++i)
    {
        std::get<i>(t);
    }    
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto ret = multiple_return_values();
    foo(ret);
}
```

Because `i` can't be `const` or we wouldn't be able to implement it. But for loops are a compile-time construct that can be evaluated statically. Compilers are free to remove it, transform it, fold it, unroll it or do whatever they want with it thanks to the as-if rule. But then why can't loops be used in a constexpr manner? There's nothing in this code that needs to be done at "runtime". Compiler optimizations are proof of that.

I know that you could potentially modify `i` inside the body of the loop, but the compiler can still be able to detect that. Example:

```
// ...snip...

template <typename T>
constexpr int foo(T t)
{
    /* Dead code */
    for (auto i = 0u; i < std::tuple_size<T>::value; ++i)
    {
    }    
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto ret = multiple_return_values();
    /* No error */
    std::array<int, foo(ret)> arr;
}
```

Since `std::get<>()` is a compile-time construct, unlike `std::cout.operator<<`, I can't see why it's disallowed.

Comment: Err...for loops don't happen at compile-time. They have to be emitted into the executable by the compiler where they then are executed at ***runtime***.

Comment: In general, for loops can't be compile -time evaluated.  You're talking about a very specific case.  But the same argument could then be used for just about any construct, not just for loops.

Comment: Well, loops may be _kinda_ a compile-time expression when the compiler decides to unroll a loop

Comment: The statement `std::get<i>(t);` has no effect. Once you put sensible code in there, the problems with your proposal ought to become a lot clearer.

Comment: The idea behind a a compile-time expression is that it is supposed to be an *expression*. `for`-loops are statements that mutate state. If the goal is to get a final value, then a recursive expression should be available.

Comment: `D` language's `foreach` can be used at compile time.

Comment: @coyotte508 All those happy `D` coders, what a pity.

Comment: There's no conceptual problem with "constexpr for", it just isn't in the language (yet).

Comment: @user6416815 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308812/why-is-c11-constexpr-so-restrictive and [this specific answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17710588/835629).

Comment: https://youtu.be/AgatxxXNwBM minute 47:44 about new `for...` keyword.

Comment: an implementation like `std::get<i>` *is* possible because of `std::integral_constant`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630843/achieving-constexpr-for-with-indexing

Answer (score 19):

Here's a way to do it that does not need too much boilerplate, inspired from http://stackoverflow.com/a/26902803/1495627 :

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct num { static const constexpr auto value = N; };

template <class F, std::size_t... Is>
void for_(F func, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
  using expander = int[];
  (void)expander{0, ((void)func(num<Is>{}), 0)...};
}

template <std::size_t N, typename F>
void for_(F func)
{
  for_(func, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Then you can do :

```
for_<N>([&] (auto i) {      
  std::get<i.value>(t); // do stuff
});
```

If you have a C++17 compiler accessible, it can be simplified to

```
template <class F, std::size_t... Is>
void for_(F func, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
  (func(num<Is>{}), ...);
}
```

Answer (score 18):

πάντα ῥεῖ gave a good and useful answer, I would like to mention another issue though with `constexpr for`.

In C++, at the most fundamental level, all expressions have a type which can be determined statically (at compile-time). There are things like RTTI and `boost::any` of course, but they are built on top of this framework, and the static type of an expression is an important concept for understanding some of the rules in the standard.

Suppose that you can iterate over a heterogenous container using a fancy for syntax, like this maybe:

```
std::tuple<int, float, std::string> my_tuple;
for (const auto & x : my_tuple) {
  f(x);
}
```

Here, `f` is some overloaded function. Clearly, the intended meaning of this is to call different overloads of `f` for each of the types in the tuple. What this really means is that in the expression `f(x)`, overload resolution has to run three different times. If we play by the current rules of C++, the only way this can make sense is if we basically unroll the loop into three different loop bodies, *before* we try to figure out what the types of the expressions are.

What if the code is actually

```
for (const auto & x : my_tuple) {
  auto y = f(x);
}
```

`auto` is not magic, it doesn't mean "no type info", it means, "deduce the type, please, compiler". But clearly, there really need to be three different types of `y` in general.

On the other hand, there are tricky issues with this kind of thing -- in C++ the parser needs to be able to know what names are types and what names are templates in order to correctly parse the language. Can the parser be modified to do some loop unrolling of `constexpr for` loops before all the types are resolved? I don't know but I think it might be nontrivial. Maybe there is a better way...

To avoid this issue, in current versions of C++, people use the visitor pattern. The idea is that you will have an overloaded function or function object and it will be applied to each element of the sequence. Then each overload has its own "body" so there's no ambiguity as to the types or meanings of the variables in them. There are libraries like `boost::fusion` or `boost::hana` that let you do iteration over heterogenous sequences using a given vistior -- you would use their mechanism instead of a for-loop.

If you could do `constexpr for` with just ints, e.g.

```
for (constexpr i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { ... }
```

this raises the same difficulty as heterogenous for loop. If you can use `i` as a template parameter inside the body, then you can make variables that refer to different types in different runs of the loop body, and then it's not clear what the static types of the expressions should be.

So, I'm not sure, but I think there may be some nontrivial technical issues associated with actually adding a `constexpr for` feature to the language. The visitor pattern / the planned reflection features may end up being less of a headache IMO... who knows.

---

Let me give another example I just thought of that shows the difficulty involved.

In normal C++, the compiler knows the static type of every variable on the stack, and so it can compute the layout of the stack frame for that function.

You can be sure that the address of a local variable won't change while the function is executing. For instance,

```
std::array<int, 3> a{{1,2,3}};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    auto x = a[i];
    int y = 15;
    std::cout << &y << std::endl;
}
```

In this code, `y` is a local variable in the body of a for loop. It has a well-defined address throughout this function, and the address printed by the compiler will be the same each time.

What should be the behavior of similar code with constexpr for?

```
std::tuple<int, long double, std::string> a{};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    auto x = std::get<i>(a);
    int y = 15;
    std::cout << &y << std::endl;
}
```

The point is that the type of `x` is deduced differently in each pass through the loop -- since it has a different type, it may have different size and alignment on the stack. Since `y` comes after it on the stack, that means that `y` might change its address on different runs of the loop -- right?

What should be the behavior if a pointer to `y` is taken in one pass through the loop, and then dereferenced in a later pass? Should it be undefined behavior, even though it would probably be legal in the similar "no-constexpr for" code with `std::array` showed above?

Should the address of `y` not be allowed to change? Should the compiler have to pad the address of `y` so that the largest of the types in the tuple can be accommodated before `y`? Does that mean that the compiler can't simply unroll the loops and start generating code, but must unroll every instance of the loop before-hand, then collect all of the type information from each of the `N` instantiations and then find a satisfactory layout?

I think you are better off just using a pack expansion, it's a lot more clear how it is supposed to be implemented by the compiler, and how efficient it's going to be at compile and run time.

Comment: for is definitely doable in constexpr, its by standard

Comment: @Sergei: on the contrary, what OP proposes, where the loop variable can be used as a template parameter in the body of for loop, is not doable in `constexpr` by the standard

Comment: I meant the problem is by standard. Not implemented by design. Possible implementations are: 1) compile and launch code at compile time 2) instantiate templates for each iteration

Comment: `for (constexpr i` if it was possible, can simply be unrolled at compile time, ie the loop dissolves into generated code with potentially entirely different code per iteration. Can't believe nobody proposed it yet. Looping over variadic arguments and tuples shouldn't be as horribly painful as it is atm.

Comment: @rustyx if that is how it will work, then in my example, the address of `y` will be different at every iteration. How will debuggers like gdb cope with this? How will we emit debug info? Will we emit debug info `n` times for the variable `y` if there are `n` iterations of the loop? What if it's a `static int y`, what should be the behavior? Should there really be `n` different `y`'s or just one? there's a lot of complexity here, it's not enough to just say "unroll at compile time" because C++ has a ton of features, all of which can appear in a for loop.

Comment: If hana::for_each is doable, constexpr for is doable.

Comment: Yes -- it is doable with the syntax and semantics used in hana::for_each :) In hana for_each, the loop variable does not have a single static type, instead its an argument to a lambda that can be different on each iteration. that's how you bypass this problem.

Comment: I mean you could choose to specify that "`constexpr for` is syntactic sugar for a tuple and a lambda, and the compiler unwinds the sugar at compile-time", but thats going to impose a lot of constraints on the `for( ... ; ... ; ...)` parts, and it's going to look very different when you actually work with such code. Why try to make it look exactly like a for loop when it's actually completely different?

Comment: @ChrisBeck "Will we emit debug info n times for the variable y if there are n iterations of the loop?" Yes, of course. "Should there really be n different y's ... ?" Yes of course. There is simply no problem here: it's exactly the same as having an overloaded `template <size_t i>` function which recursively calls itself to perform the loop (or some similar variant), which is what you currently have to do anyway. `static` variables would follow the same rules i.e. one per iteration, but I agree that is a bit subtle.

Answer (score 9):

In **C++20** most of the `std::algorithm` functions will be `constexpr`. For example using `std::transform`, many operations requiring a loop can be done at compile time. Consider this example **calculating the factorial of every number in an array at compile time** (adapted from [Boost.Hana documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-introduction)):

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr int factorial(int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename F>
constexpr std::array<std::result_of_t<F(T)>, N>
transform_array(std::array<T, N> array, F f) {
    auto array_f = std::array<std::result_of_t<F(T)>, N>{};
    // This is a constexpr "loop":
    std::transform(array.begin(), array.end(), array_f.begin(), [&f](auto el){return f(el);});
    return array_f;
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::array<int, 4> ints{{1, 2, 3, 4}};
    // This can be done at compile time!
    constexpr std::array<int, 4> facts = transform_array(ints, factorial);
    static_assert(facts == std::array<int, 4>{{1, 2, 6, 24}}, "");
}
```

See how the array `facts` can be computed at compile time using a "*loop*", i.e. an `std::algorithm`. At the time of writing this, you need an experimental version of the newest clang or gcc release which you can try out on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/). But soon C++20 will be fully implemented by all the major compilers in the release versions.

Answer (score 3):

This proposal "Expansion Statements" is interesting and I will provide the link for you to read further explanations.

[Click this link](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1306r1.pdf)

The proposal introduced the syntactic sugar `for...` as similar to the `sizeof...` operator. `for...` loop statement is a **compile-time expression** which means it has nothing to do in the **runtime**.

For example:

```
std::tuple<int, float, char> Tup1 {5, 3.14, 'K'};
for... (auto elem : Tup1) {
     std::cout << elem << " "; 
}
```

The compiler will generate the code at the compile-time and this is the equivalence:

```
std::tuple<int, float, char> Tup1 {5, 3.14, 'K'};
{
  auto elem = std::get<0>(Tup1);
  std::cout << elem << " ";
}
{
  auto elem = std::get<1>(Tup1);
  std::cout << elem << " ";
}
{
  auto elem = std::get<2>(Tup1);
  std::cout << elem << " ";
}
```

Thus, the expansion statement is not a loop but a repeated version of the loop body as it was said in the document.

Since this proposal isn't in C++'s current version or in the technical specification (if it's accepted). We can use the alternative version from the boost library specifically `<boost/hana/for_each.hpp>` and use the tuple version of boost from `<boost/hana/tuple.hpp>`. Click this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854510/iterating-over-boosthanatuple).

```
#include <boost/hana/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
using namespace boost;

...

hana::tuple<int, std::string, float> Tup1 {5, "one", 5.55};
hana::for_each(Tup1, [](auto&& x){
    std::cout << x << " ";
});

// Which will print:
// 5 "one" 5.55
```

The first argument of `boost::hana::for_each` must be a foldable container.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't a for-loop a compile-time expression?

Because a `for()` loop is used to define **runtime control flow** in the c++ language.

Generally variadic templates cannot be unpacked within runtime control flow statements in c++.

```
 std::get<i>(t);
```

cannot be deduced at compile time, since `i` is a runtime variable.

Use [variadic template parameter unpacking](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead.

---

You might also find this post useful (if this not even remarks a duplicate having answers for your question):

[iterate over tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple)

Comment: You're just saying "because it is that way". You haven't actually answered the question.

Comment: @Veedrac: but that is essentially the answer - is because it's the way the language is defined.

Comment: @Veedrac Well, what else do you think I should answer? `for()` isn't designed for compile time constructs, and will never be, period.

Comment: @Veedrac That answer basically boils down to "because it is that way" though.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Of course it's because that's how the language is defined. But that's a useless comment because almost any question can be dismissed as "because that's how the language is defined". The question is about why the language is defined that way, and what rules make it so.

Comment: @Veedrac Nothing to do with the purpose and workings of `for()` at all. You may live in dreams, but they'll never become true.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper With the crucial distinction that it explains why. Aka. if someone asked why signed overflow is undefined, saying "because it's what the spec says" is useless without a *why*.

Comment: IOW, your argument could be equally applied to a case where it's wrong. Aka. "x : y ? z / recursion / etc.  is used to defined runtime control flow ergo is banned". It offers no *discriminatory power*, ergo has zero entropy.

Comment: @Veedrac No, it's pure speculation. Saying "you'd have to ask the standards committee why" is the same as "because that's the way it is".

Comment: @Veedrac They talk confused sir.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper lol I linked to the wrong post. [I meant this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8309141/1763356)

Comment: Too be honest I don't think it can be considered a duplicate... The question is asking "why", not "how can I do this", OP already knows how to metaprogram it. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308812/why-is-c11-constexpr-so-restrictive) we see that `constexpr` lost part of its restrictions (used to be a single statement, now we can use if/else), it's not a dream to imagine that sometime we can also use for in it.

Comment: @coyotte508 The problem is not `constexpr`. The issue will still be the same if you put a for loop in main. Either way it just sounds like the OP is complaining rather than genuinely wondering why.

Comment: I'll vote to reopen after I gather 66 more reputation then. And @sleeptightpupper code [such as this](https://ideone.com/ZcdlHj) would cause problems if not in `constexpr`, it's why it can be expected that OP's code *could* work in `constexpr`.

Comment: @coyotte508 For one thing, you have a `cout` statement in there, which makes it not `constexpr`.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper ok, removed that one, but not the one on line 11. But, ok. Although the link I first gave has a reference to [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3597.html), partly implemented as `if` / `else` are now allowed in `constexpr` but mutable variables (with behavior that can be deduced at compile time) are still not. The case of the `for` loop in a constexpr is also mentioned there, and in my opinion answers the OP's question precisely. And it's not really an answer to the question which this is a duplicate of.

Comment: πάνταῥεῖ, I also think it's not a dupe, for the reason @coyotte508 stated. And to be honest, I think it's a bit unfair to answer **and** dupe-hammer a question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @alain Well, I reopened the question. Come up with your better answers please.

Comment: ... pigheaded fellows, wasting appropriate close votes.

Comment: Thanks πάντα ῥεῖ! I do have some thought about it, but I'm not sure enough to post an answer. I would really love to see other answers to this question. (I'm not saying your answer is bad, and I didn't dv it).

Comment: Well, I can offer you to vote to close another question on your behalf if you want...

Comment: @alain Well, you tell me I reopened the question for such _wishy washy_ _"may be I have an answer, but I'm actually to shy to post it"_?

Comment: I have an answer, but I flagged the question as a duplicate (of the first link I gave), so I thought it was inappropriate to post it.  Still, I commented on the OP.

Comment: I voted to reopen because I think it's not a dupe, but an interesting question. That's all.

Comment: @alain _"because I think it's not a dupe, but an interesting question"_ How does this contradict? There's not much expectation for getting  more and better answers.

Comment: Ok, an *unanswered* interesting question. I'm interested in the reasons why certain constructs can not be used as `constexpr`, while the C++ template system is turing-complete. I think it has more to do with expressing a programmers intents, than with technical reasons. That's unanswered in the other question.

Comment: @alain Well, again: `for()` never was meant to purpose for such stuff like unpacking templates.How should it, as it was introduced with the c language.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ for loop do can be used in compile time :constexpr int getsum(int n){
    int s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < to; i++){
        s += i;
    }
    return s;
}  ;    get<getsum(20)>(tuple_variable);

Comment: `if` also defines **runtime control flow**. But we still do have `if constexpr` since C++17.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples attempting to replicate a compile-time for loop (which isn't part of the language at this time), using fold expressions and `std::integer_sequence`. The first example shows a simple assignment in the loop, and the second example shows tuple indexing and uses a lambda with template parameters available in C++20.

For a function with a template parameter, e.g.

```cpp
template <int n>
constexpr int factorial() {
    if constexpr (n == 0) { return 1; }
    else { return n * factorial<n - 1>(); }
}
```

Where we want to loop over the template parameter, like this:

```cpp
template <int N>
constexpr auto example() {
    std::array<int, N> vals{};
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        vals[i] = factorial<i>(); // this doesn't work
    }
    return vals;
}
```

One can do this:

```cpp
template <int... Is>
constexpr auto get_array(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> a) -> std::array<int, a.size()> {
    std::array<int, a.size()> vals{};
    ((vals[Is] = factorial<Is>()), ...);
    return vals;
}
```

And then get the result at compile time:

```cpp
constexpr auto x = get_array(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 5>{});
// x = {1, 1, 2, 6, 24}
```

Similarly, for a tuple:

```cpp
constexpr auto multiple_return_values()
{
    return std::make_tuple(3, 3.14, "pi");
}

int main(void) {
    static constexpr auto ret = multiple_return_values();
    constexpr auto for_constexpr = [&]<int... Is>(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> a) {
        ((std::get<Is>(ret)), ...); // std::get<i>(t); from the question
        return 0;
    }

    // use it:
    constexpr auto w = for_constexpr(std::make_integer_sequence<int, std::tuple_size_v<decltype(ret)>>{});
}
```