# Iterating over boost::hana::tuple

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

I could not find a way to access real object with `hana::for_each` iterating over tuples.

```
struct A {
  std::string name;
}

struct B {
  std::string name;
}

using type_t = decltype(boost::hana::tuple_t<A, B>);
type_t names;

boost::hana::for_each(names, [&](const auto& a) {
      std::cout << a.name << std::endl;
    });
```

Type of `a` appears to be `hana::tuple_impl<...>` and seems to be not-castable to its underlying type `decltype(std::decay_t<a>)::type`.

I basically want to iterate over a list of templated objects (containers) that have the same interface but contain different values. Better ways to achieve this is welcome.

Comment: I doubt this `decltype(boost::hana::tuple_t<A, B>)`. What does this mean? Isn't `tuple_t<A,B>` a *type* itself?

Comment: @Nawaz Documentation says its usage is like this `auto types = hana::tuple_t<int*, char&, void>;` So I guess it is a C++14 variable template. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`tuple_t`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1tuple.html#a1997546daf58a48cc15498d338a03da3) is for a tuple of `hana::type`s. You want a `tuple` of normal objects, which is just `tuple`:

```
boost::hana::tuple<A, B> names;
boost::hana::for_each(names, [&](const auto& x) {
    std::cout << x.name << std::endl;
});
```

Comment: It does work. Can you elaborate when to use hana types a little bit and what are they for exactly? Documentation is a bit misleading about it. It talks like I _have to_ wrap objects (which are not integral, `tuple_c` is for integrals) to `hana_types` and `tupe_t` is the easy way to do it.

Comment: @Etherealone `tuple_t<Ts...>` is approximately a wrapper for `tuple<type_c<Ts>...>`. You use it when you want `type_c`s.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if I got it but it looks like I would use `tuple_t` to operate on types in an MPL-ish way (hana operates on objects of type `hana_type` and allows us to work on actual C++ types via these objects (values)). And normal tuple is for normal object usage.

Comment: @Etherealone Yes, this is it.

Comment: @LouisDionne Oh hey Louis :)