# std::get<N> only accept const expression, how to bypass the restriction?

Tags: c++, std, c++17

I am trying to simulate the std::visit function in c++17 (gcc7.1)

```
template<typename ... Ts>
void myvisit(variant<Ts...> v)
{

    size_t N = std::variant_size<decltype(v)>::value;
    for (int i=0;i<N;++i) //try to iterate variadic pack
    {
        using T = decltype(get<i>(v));
        if (holds_alternative<T>(v))
        {
            cout<< get<T>(v);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    using VAR = variant<int, string, double>;
    vector<VAR> vv;
    vv.push_back("app");
    vv.push_back(123);
    vv.push_back(1.02);
    for(auto v:vv)
        myvisit(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Here I get an issue that:

> error: the value of ‘i’ is not usable in a constant expression
>   using T = decltype(get < i >(v));

I am wondering how to solve it?

Comment: This is where you meet [`std::integer_sequence` and friends](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). :-]

Comment: Why would you implement `std::visit` in this fashion?

Comment: @NicolBolas just to get familiar with c++17 feature :)

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks! I will look into it.

Comment: @camino: I didn't ask why you would implement `visit`. I asked why you would implement it *in this fashion*, with a loop. It's like implementing array access by doing a `for` loop over the array until you get to the given index.

Comment: @NicolBolas is there any better way to do that? I only can figure out this method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked but... what about as follows? 
`template <typename ... Ts> void myvisit (variant<Ts...> v) { using unused = int[]; unused { 0, ((holds_alternative<Ts>(v) ? (std::cout << get<Ts>(v), 0) : 0), 0)... }; }`

Comment: @max66 I got a compile error when calling your function. for example: variant<string,int> v; v=123; myvisit(v);

Comment: sorry: my example compile but I've simulated with very very simplified classes; which kind of error do you get?

Comment: @max66,  error: no matching function for call to ‘holds_alternative<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>(std::variant<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>&)’
    (holds_alternative<Ts...>(v) ? (std::cout << get<Ts>(v), 0) : 0)

Comment: sorry: transcription error (that I've corrected immediatly): is `holds_alternative<Ts>(v)`, not `holds_alternative<Ts...>(v)`; I also suggest to add `(void)` before the second `unused` (to avoid some warnings).

Comment: The full (I hope correct) example: `template <typename ... Ts> void myvisit (variant<Ts...> v) { using unused = int[]; (void)unused { 0, ((holds_alternative<Ts>(v) ? (std::cout << get<Ts>(v), 0) : 0), 0)... };}`

Comment: @max66 It works now. That 's awesome solution! Thanks so much!!

Comment: @camino : Except that you very likely want `v.index()`, _not_ `holds_alternative<Ts>(v)`... ;-] The latter simply returns whether a type is unique in the list of alternatives, not whether it is the active variant alternative.

Comment: @ildjarn I change it to void myvisit( ..... ){std::cout << get<v.index()>(v)<<endl;} but got an error: error: no matching function for call to ‘get<v.std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double>::index()>(std::variant<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double>&)’

Comment: @camino : `variant::index()` isn't constexpr and so isn't usable directly in that way. If it were that easy they wouldn't bother including the complex `std::visit`... ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn I checked cppreference.com, it shows that constexpr std::size_t index() const noexcept ,

Comment: @camino : I meant in _this_ context, since `v` is not constexpr object. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn I see, Thanks a lot, anyway

Comment: my question is answered in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602057/why-isnt-a-for-loop-a-compile-time-expression/37602149#37602149