# Initialization of a Boost point C++

Tags: c++, boost, constants, boost-geometry

I'm using the Boost libraries to manipulate points in a N-dimensional domain. The problem is that I cannot find a way to initialize them without setting each coordinate separately.

To get or set coordinates with this library, one should use :

```
bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point1; // Declaration
point1.set<0>(1.0);                                    // Coordinate 0 set 
point1.set<1>(2.0);                                    // Coordinate 1 set
double x = point1.get<0>();                            // Coordinate 0 get
double y = point1.get<1>();                            // Coordinate 1 get
```

You can find example and information at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_point.html

However, I work with points in a N-dimensional space, with N > 100, and I cannot afford to write a line of code for each coordinate manually. But something like this :

```
bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point1;
for(int i(0); i<NDIM; ++i){
    point1.set<i>(1.0);
}
```

does not work, because the index of the coordinates needs to be a const value. Could you help me find a way to automatically initialize the coordinates? I tried a lot of things, nothing worked !

Comment: Probably related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602057/why-isnt-a-for-loop-a-compile-time-expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use variadic templates and `std::index_sequence` to deduce indexes from `NDIM` and process all together using the unpacking syntax:

```
template <class Point, size_t... I>
void init(Point& p, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    int dummy[] = { (p.set<I>(1.0), 0)... };
    (void)dummy;
}
```

The syntax `(void_func(), 0)` calls a void function, but returns `0`. This is necessary because you cannot use the unpack syntax `...` for void functions. Assigning it to an array and using that (e.g. casting it to `void`) makes sure nothing gets optimized away.

Then call this function like so:

```
init(point1, std::make_index_sequence<NDIM>());
```

Note that `NDIM` must be `const`.

For more details on how `index_sequence` works take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).