# Achieving 'constexpr for' with indexing

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++20, constexpr

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    std::get<i>(tuple);
}
```

this doesn't compile, since `i` is not a compile time constant. On [How can you iterate over the elements of an std::tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/how-can-you-iterate-over-the-elements-of-an-stdtuple) and other posts I see answers of recursion, or using `std::apply`, but those lose the index control. I also don't want to limit myself soley on `std::tuple`.

---

Whenever I have to loop over something at compile time I have to stop and think and do weird things especially when I try to achieve non-standard iterations like reverse, custom increment, or involve multiple indices in the same statements such as `std::get<i>(tuple) * std::get<i + 1>(tuple)`.

---

with [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) what is the closest we can have to a `constexpr for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to make a `constexpr_for<N>(F&& function)` implementation that uses [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to expand the `Size` as `0, 1, ... N - 1` onto a templated lambda, which calls the function with a [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) parameter. This parameter implicitly converts the struct's template argument to `size_t` via its `constexpr operator value_type() const noexcept;` operator.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<size_t Size, typename F>
constexpr void constexpr_for(F&& function) {
    auto unfold = [&]<size_t... Ints>(std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
        (std::forward<F>(function)(std::integral_constant<size_t, Ints>{}), ...);
    };

    unfold(std::make_index_sequence<Size>());
}
```

This enables the `std::get<i>` behaviour:

```
auto tuple = std::make_tuple(0ull, 1, 2.0, "3", '4');
constexpr size_t size = std::tuple_size_v<decltype(tuple)>;

constexpr_for<size>([&](auto i) {
    std::cout << std::get<i>(tuple) << ' ';
});
//prints 0 1 2 3 4
```

with the `[&]` capture there is access to `size` so reverse-iterating can be achieved:

```
constexpr_for<size>([&](auto i) {
    std::cout << std::get<size - i - 1>(tuple) << ' ';
});
//prints 4 3 2 1 0
```

or e.g. iterate over odd indices by checking against out of bounds attempts:

```
constexpr_for<size>([&](auto i) {
    constexpr auto idx = (i * 2 + 1);
    if constexpr (idx < size) {
        std::cout << std::get<idx>(tuple) << ' ';
    }
});
//prints 1 3
```

Comment: `auto` in functions templates in C++20, but `auto` in lambdas is C++14.  Also, you should use `std::integral_constant` instead of creating your own - it's more typical for this problem. If you want to pass the max size, that can be a 2nd parameter (or just... not, since the user provided it to begin with).

Comment: thanks for taking a look Barry. I didn't know about `std::integral_constant`, I will use it in this and future implementations.

Comment: This is *very* spicy.  What was screwing with me was `auto apply` for your lambda, since `std::apply` is a thing.  Once I separated that out, it made sense how the fold expression was working (I think).

Comment: You don't need to capture `size` either, it's a constant.