# why for-loop isn't a compile time expression and extended constexpr allows for-loop in a constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

I wrote code like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
constexpr int getsum(int to){
    int s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < to; i++){
        s += i;
    }
    return s;
}
int main() {
    constexpr int s = getsum(10);
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that it works because of [extended constexpr](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#extended-constexpr). However in this question [why-isnt-a-for-loop-a-compile-time-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602057/why-isnt-a-for-loop-a-compile-time-expression), the author gave his code as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

constexpr auto multiple_return_values()
{
    return std::make_tuple(3, 3.14, "pi");
}

template <typename T>
constexpr void foo(T t)
{
    for (auto i = 0u; i < std::tuple_size<T>::value; ++i)
    {
        std::get<i>(t);
    }    
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto ret = multiple_return_values();
    foo(ret);
}
```

It could not compile by GCC5.1, however, after replacing `std::get<i>(t);` with something without a specified template parameter his code did work.
After reading answers under this question I found their main point is `constexpr for` creates trouble for the compiler so for-loop is used at run-time.
So it makes me confused, on one hand, `for-loop` is at run-time, on the other, the loop is in a `constexpr` function, so it must be calculated at compile time, so there seems to be a contradiction. I just wonder where did I make a mistake.

Comment: `constexpr` doesn't mean it definitely runs at compile-time. `constexpr` functions are meant to work at both compile-time and runtime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20437229/440403 I think this is the best answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with whether or not the `constexpr` function needs to be able to be runnable at compile-time (`tuple_size<T>::value` is a constant expression regardless of whether the `T` comes from a `constexpr` object or not).

`std::get<>` is a function template, that requires an integral constant expression to be called. In this loop:

```
for (auto i = 0u; i < std::tuple_size<T>::value; ++i)
{
    std::get<i>(t);
}
```

`i` is not an integral constant expression. It's not even constant. `i` changes throughout the loop and assumes every value from `0` to `tuple_size<T>::value`. While it kind of looks like it, this isn't calling a function with different values of `i` - this is calling *different functions* every time. There is no support in the language at the moment for this sort of iteration<sup>†</sup>, and this is substantively different from the original example, where we're just summing ints.

That is, in one case, we're looping over `i` and invoking `f(i)`, and in other, we're looping over `i` and invoking `f<i>()`. The second one has more preconditions on it than the first one.

---

<sup>†</sup>If such language support is ever added, probably in the form of a `constexpr for` statement, that support would be independent from `constexpr` functions anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Your​ function need to be valid both at runtime and at compile time. So your Variant `i` can be seen as a runtime variable. If the function is executed at compile time, the variable `i` is part of the compiler's runtime. So a `int` in a constexpr function is under the same rules as a `int` in a non-constexpr function.

What you can do is to create your​ own constexpr for loop:

```
template<typename F, std::size_t... S>
constexpr void static_for(F&& function, std::index_sequence<S...>) {
    int unpack[] = {0,
        void(function(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, S>{})), 0)...
    };

    (void) unpack;
}

template<std::size_t iterations, typename F>
constexpr void static_for(F&& function) {
    static_for(std::forward<F>(function), std::make_index_sequence<iterations>());
}
```

Then, you can use your `static_for` like this:

```
static_for<std::tuple_size<T>::value>([&](auto index) {
    std::get<index>(t);
});
```

---

Note that lambda function cannot be used in constexpr function until C++17, so you can instead roll your own functor:

```
template<typename T>
struct Iteration {
    T& tuple;

    constexpr Iteration(T& t) : tuple{t} {}

    template<typename I>
    constexpr void operator() (I index) const {
        std::get<index>(tuple);
    }
};
```

And now you can use `static_for` like that:

```
static_for<std::tuple_size<T>::value>(Iteration{t});
```

Comment: Why is so complicated? Is that not enough: `template<typename F> constexpr void static_for_lt(F && function, size_t from, size_t to) { if (from < to) { static_for_lt(std::forward<F>(function), from + 1, to); } }` ?

Comment: @Andry I have difficulty understanding your code snippet. First you don't ever call `function`. Also, your code don't make `from` nor `to` available as compile time constants to the body of `function`.

Comment: Could not edit my comment. I meant with the call inside the if. Why this does not solve the problem?

Comment: I've found better workaround for not allowed declarations in constexpr functions: `template <typename T> void static_consume(std::initializer_list<T>) {} template<typename F, std::size_t... S> constexpr void static_for(F && function, std::index_sequence<S...>) { return static_consume({ (function(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, S>{}), 0)... }); }`

Comment: @Andry you can post this as an answer if you wish. I don't think such code is worth doing in C++11 because the lack of generic lambda and C++14 allows declarations in constexpr function. It may still help someone stuck with C++11 though.

Answer (score 1):

Some better approach as [Guillaume Racicot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42006019/6951728) have mentioned with workaround of a bit unfinished `constexpr` support and `std::size` in such compilers like `Visual Studio 2015 Update 3` and so.

```
#include <tuple>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

// std::size is supported from C++17
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t static_size(const T (&)[N]) noexcept
{
    return N;
}

template <typename ...T>
constexpr size_t static_size(const std::tuple<T...> &)
{
    return std::tuple_size<std::tuple<T...> >::value;
}

template<typename Functor>
void runtime_for_lt(Functor && function, size_t from, size_t to)
{
    if (from < to) {
        function(from);
        runtime_for_lt(std::forward<Functor>(function), from + 1, to);
    }
}

template <template <typename T_> class Functor, typename T>
void runtime_foreach(T & container)
{
    runtime_for_lt(Functor<T>{ container }, 0, static_size(container));
}

template <typename Functor, typename T>
void runtime_foreach(T & container, Functor && functor)
{
    runtime_for_lt(functor, 0, static_size(container));
}

template <typename T>
void static_consume(std::initializer_list<T>) {}

template<typename Functor, std::size_t... S>
constexpr void static_foreach_seq(Functor && function, std::index_sequence<S...>) {
    return static_consume({ (function(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, S>{}), 0)... });
}

template<std::size_t Size, typename Functor>
constexpr void static_foreach(Functor && functor) {
    return static_foreach_seq(std::forward<Functor>(functor), std::make_index_sequence<Size>());
}
```

**Usage:**

```
using mytuple = std::tuple<char, int, long>;

template <typename T>
struct MyTupleIterator
{
    T & ref;

    MyTupleIterator(T & r) : ref(r) {}

    void operator() (size_t index) const
    {
        // still have to do with switch
        assert(index < static_size(ref));
        size_t value;
        switch(index) {
            case 0: value = std::get<0>(ref); break;
            case 1: value = std::get<1>(ref); break;
            case 2: value = std::get<2>(ref); break;
        }
        printf("%u: %u\n", unsigned(index), unsigned(value));
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct MyConstexprTupleIterator
{
    T & ref;

    constexpr MyConstexprTupleIterator(T & r) : ref(r) {}

    constexpr void operator() (size_t index) const
    {
        // lambda workaround for:
        //  * msvc2015u3: `error C3250: 'value': declaration is not allowed in 'constexpr' function body`
        //  * gcc 5.x: `error: uninitialized variable ‘value’ in ‘constexpr’ function`
        [&]() {
          // still have to do with switch
          assert(index < static_size(ref));
          size_t value;
          switch(index) {
              case 0: value = std::get<0>(ref); break;
              case 1: value = std::get<1>(ref); break;
              case 2: value = std::get<2>(ref); break;
          }
          printf("%u: %u\n", unsigned(index), unsigned(value));
        }();
    }
};

int main()
{
    mytuple t = std::make_tuple(10, 20, 30);
    runtime_foreach<MyTupleIterator>(t);

    mytuple t2 = std::make_tuple(40, 50, 60);
    runtime_foreach(t2, [&](size_t index) {
        // still have to do with switch
        assert(index < static_size(t2));
        size_t value;
        switch(index) {
            case 0: value = std::get<0>(t2); break;
            case 1: value = std::get<1>(t2); break;
            case 2: value = std::get<2>(t2); break;
        }
        printf("%u: %u\n", unsigned(index), unsigned(value));
    });

    mytuple t3 = std::make_tuple(70, 80, 90);
    static_foreach<std::tuple_size<decltype(t3)>::value>(MyConstexprTupleIterator<mytuple>{t3});

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
0: 10
1: 20
2: 30
0: 40
1: 50
2: 60
0: 70
1: 80
2: 90
```